# Override NPM core dependancies

Tags: javascript, npm, dependencies

The node package `ip@2.0.0` has a vulnerability, which has been patched in a patch update (`@2.0.1`)

The trouble is that this package (and version) is actually part of `npm` itself.

```
npm ls ip
npm@10.4.0 /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.1/lib/node_modules/npm
└─┬ make-fetch-happen@13.0.0
  └─┬ @npmcli/agent@2.2.0
    └─┬ socks-proxy-agent@8.0.2
      └─┬ socks@2.7.1
        └── ip@2.0.0
```

How can I can I override this dependancy?